# Generate menu links for a view with contextual filter and parameters in the path

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a view with a contextual filter, and a few tabs corresponding to a taxonomy. In my `module.links.menu.yml` I have something like this:

```
mymodule.apple_view:
  title: 'List of apples'
  route_name: view.fruit_view.page_1
  route_parameters: { fruittype: 'apple' }
  menu_name: main
```

So I have my tab "List of apples", but the URL has the form http://localhost/it/fruit_view?fruittype=apple (which works), but I'd rather have it as http://localhost/it/fruit_view/apple (which also works). I suppose there may be a parameter for `.link.menu.yml` to achieve this, but I cannot find the full documentation. I checked [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Menu!menu.api.php/group/menu/8.6.x) and the source, but that didn't help. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - solved it. In the view definition, I changed the path from `/fruit_view` to `/fruit_view/%fruittype`, and I got the URLs as I wanted them. I also had to remove the menu voice defined in the view, but that's not a problem, since I have to redefine the filtered ones anyway.