# Programmatic menu link for a view with contextual filter and no parameters in the path

Tags: views, routes

Related question (my question is when contextual filters are NOT in the path): [Generate menu links for a view with contextual filter and parameters in the path](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271155/generate-menu-links-for-a-view-with-contextual-filter-and-parameters-in-the-path)

In `mymodule.links.menu.yml` I have defined a link:

```
MYMODULE.fruits-apple:
  title: 'Apple'
  route_name: view.fruit_list.page_apple
  parent: MYMODULE.fruits
  weight: 5
  menu_name: fruits-navigation
```

The view page `view.fruit_list.page_apple` has the path `/fruits/apple`.

When on a page other than `/fruits/apple`, the link appears in my menu and allows access to the view. When on the parent page (`/fruits`), it appears expanded under the parent link in the menu.  But, on `/fruits/apple`, the link is not shown.

I checked the route with `/devel/routes` and found this:

**Route name**: `view.fruit_list.page_apple`
**Path**: `/fruits/apple/{arg_0}`

I think the problem is that I am not setting `{arg_0}` in `mymodule.links.menu.yml`.  I think this is the problem because I have links to views with routes that do not have `{arg_0}` in them and they display properly.

`{arg_0}` is a contextual filter for the **User ID**:

When the value is NOT in the URL: Provide default value (User ID from logged in user)

I am using the view path as `/fruits/apple`, so I never explicitly set the user ID for the contextual filter; instead, I rely on Views to automatically pull in the value.

In this case, how can I set the route parameter `{arg_0}` for my view so that the menu link appears properly on the view path?

I tried adding `route_parameters: { arg_0: '' }` and `route_parameters: { arg_0: 'NULL' }`, but that didn't help.

**MORE DEBUGGING**

When I create a link in the menu UI to the path `/fruits/apple` and then go the page `/fruits/apple`, I see BOTH my menu UI link and my module-defined link.  But if I disable or delete my menu UI link, then my module-defined link is not shown.

In the same way, I can create a menu link using the options in the Views UI, which also causes both my Views UI menu link + module-defined menu link to be displayed on `/fruits/apple`.  When I remove the Views UI link, the module-defined link is also no longer displayed.

If I delete the contextual filter on my view, then the module-defined link is also shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "on the view url for view.fruit_list.page_apple, the link is not shown."? Are you saying that the link disappears from the menu on certain urls?

Comment: @sonfd I rewrote that section with the paths so it should be clear now.

Comment: Can you please clarify how a view page `/fruits/apple` does generate a route `/fruits/apple/{arg_0}`? Normally you would need a placeholder `%` to do this.

Comment: @4k4 `{arg_0}` is a contextual filter on the User ID.  I configured it with the option "When the value is NOT in the URL: Provide default value (User ID from logged in user)".  So Views is automatically injecting the current user's UID; I'm doing it this way because users only need to see the stuff that pertains to their own accounts.

Comment: My understanding of contextual filters is that they don't create route arguments on their own, you can even use them in non page displays like blocks which don't have a path.

Comment: Does this happen if you create the same link, but via the UI? Afaik there's nothing special about module defined menu links that would make them not appear on some urls

Comment: @4k4 The contextual filter works in the view page without any argument, but the link (just the link) is not being shown.

Comment: @sonfd No, it doesn't happen if I create the link via the UI.  See the "More debugging" I just added at the end.

Comment: Your latest edit makes sense. If both are present, route argument and contextual filter, the View can connect both and checks for a valid user. The problem is solved if you remove one of them. Since you want to keep the contextual filter I would suggest you remove the route argument.

Comment: @4k4 How do I remove the route argument though?  I deleted the contextual filter and the route argument disappears.  I re-added the contextual filter and the route argument re-appears.  I only want to use the contextual filter with the "provide default value" option so I don't need the route argument, and I didn't set it and it's not in the path, but nevertheless it's still there.

Comment: I've tested it first in the Content view and there it didn't add a route argument, but when I've used a fresh view it does. So my understanding of contextual filters was more like wishful thinking because you should have control over the path by placing placeholders when and where you want.